# How to deploy perl dancer app with cgi and calling external scripts?

Tags: perl, apache, dancer

I have had a webapp using CGI implementation. It basically uses system() calls to launch other programs and the results will be rendered in html.

Now, I am trying to implement it using Dancer. In order to run these external programs, I created a "scripts" directory in /MyApp, so it's like /MyApp/scripts. I put all my other scripts there,  which will be called in a route handler.

```
get '/analysis' => sub {
    if (session('user')  && session('logged_in')) {
    open FH, "<", "./scripts/test.out";
    my $msg = <FH>;
    close FH;
    chdir ("./scripts");
    system("call sth"); #call external programs to generate a "test.png"
    my $err;
    copy ("test.png", "../public/images/test.png") || ($err = "cannot copy"); #copy the "test.png" to public/images directory, so the 
    my $img = "test.png";
       template 'analysis',{msg => $msg, img => $img, err => $err};
    }
    else {
    return redirect '/'
   }
```

};

However, I can launch this app successfully as a standalone or using plackup/starman. But I can not deploy it with CGI. I did every step using dancer's doc regarding cgi deployment. I can successfully using cgi to launch dancer's example app. but when I tried to launch my own as above, I always got the error:

app directory '/home/tester/MyApp/bin/..' isn't writable/executable and can't chmod it at /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/Dancer/Logger.pm line 16, referer:localhost

It seems a permission problem, but I don't know how to fix it. Is there a better way to launch an external program from route handler? where should I store these external programs, thus they can be executed by the dancer app when it was deployed as CGI.

Could anyone help me? Thanks.

Xiaokuan

Comment: Seems like you have permissions set to group:none, others:none on your directory, and the web server is running under a different user (not yours). Try to chmod the relevant directories to 755, or possible 777 in the case of public/images where your code copies the test.png to. When you get it working, think about which permissions are needed where for a while, to give as little permissions to the web server as possible to prevent hacking.

Comment: I have carefully adjusted permissions. It worked well.

Answer (score 0):

[`Dancer::Logger::File` documentation](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Dancer::Logger::File) says:

> It's possible to specify a logs directory with the log_path option.
>
> ```
>      setting log_path => $dir;
> ```

Simply add a line to your (production.yml) environment file:

```
log_path: /var/log/dancer/myapp/
```

and make this path writable to `www-data`.